# SQL -- Multiple rows, similar value in a row, need to not show specific values

Tags: sql

Here is the issue:
Table name = a

```
1       2     3      
123    1      A
123    1      A
123    2      A
332    1      A
332    1      A
321    2      B
321    2      A
321    1      A
```

So far what I have is this:

```
select distinct 1,2,3 from a where a.2='1' and a.3='B';
```

What it returns is each result (except for 321).

I only want to select values column 1 as long as that value is not in a row where there is a 2 in column 2 or a B in column 3. Is this possible?

Comment: The requested result is not clear, please add it to your post.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? (`select distinct 1,2,3` is invalid standard SQL)

Comment: Sorry, I managed to figure it out myself... I should have been more clear though! Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"not in a row where there is a 2 in column 2 or a B in column 3" can be expressed as

```
select distinct 1,2,3 from a where a.2!='2' or a.3!='B';
```

or

```
select distinct 1,2,3 from a where a.2 <> '2' or a.3 <> 'B';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `group by` and `having`:

```
select col1
from t
group by col1
having sum(case when col2 = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       sum(case when col3 = 'B' then 1 else 0 end)  = 0;
```